# URL Inserted Couldn't be Clicked

Tags: vb.net, winforms, url

I have created an sql statement to retrieve data from my database. In addition, I have added a new column into the Data Grid View to display the URL link for the every row of data displayed. The URL displayed is correct, but it cannot be clicked and redirect the users to internet browser. Please do give me advice.

```
    conn = New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data 
    Source=1MDb.accdb;Persist Security Info=False;")

    strSQL = "SELECT m.primaryTitle AS MovieTitle, m.startYear AS 
    StartYear, m.runtimeMinutes AS Runtime, m.genres AS Genre, 
    d.primaryName AS Director, c.writers AS Writer, r.averageRating AS 
    Rating, d.primaryProfession AS Profession, ('www.imdb.com/title/' + 
    m.tconst) AS URL From Movie m, Director d, Crew c, Rating r WHERE 
    m.tconst=c.tconst AND d.nconst = c.directors AND r.tconst=m.tconst"

    conn.Open()
    da = New OleDbDataAdapter(strSQL, conn)
    Dim ds As New DataSet("Movies1")
    'fills the dataset with data
    da.Fill(ds, "Movies1")
    'assign the datasource to the DataGridView
    DataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables("Movies1")
    conn.Close()
```

Comment: Did you add an event handler to handle the click on your datagridviewlinkcolumn? Show the code for it

Comment: Nope I didn't....

Comment: If you had read the documentation for the `DataGridViewLinkColumn` class, which should have been the first thing you did when it didn't work, then you'd know that you have to handle the `CellContentClick` event of the grid to act on the user clicking a link.  SO is not a place to find out about things like this that can easily be found for yourself.  It's a place you come when you have already tried everything else.